# Barras se superponen entre sí en el eje X

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Al momento de graficar el diagrama de barras se presenta que algunas barras se están dibujando una encima de otra. Deberia verse alrededor de 22 barras y solo se muestran 7. (ver el svg generado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo cuando `x = 15` se muestran muchas barras superpuestas y visualmente pareciera que el valor de `y=350`.

¿Que está ocasionando este comportamiento?

**CÓDIGO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Diagrama de Barras con SVG</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            svg{
                background-color: aquamarine;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //variables liezo svg:
            var ancho = 800;
            var alto = 500;
            var dist = 3;

            var CuadroSvg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', ancho).attr('height', alto);
            //####### Leer Datos: #########
            d3.csv("./data.csv", function(d) { 
                return { 
                    Edad : d.Edad,
                    Espanola : d.Espanola,
                    Extranjera : d.Extranjera,
                    Total : d.Total
                };
            }).then( function(data) {
                //####### Tratar con los datos ########
                var Espanolas = [];
                //var Extranjeras = [];
                var Edades = [];
                var Totales = [];
                for(i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
                    Espanolas.push( data[i].Espanola );
                    //Extranjeras.push( data[i].Extranjera);
                    Edades.push( data[i].Edad);
                    Totales.push( data[i].Total);
                }
                //####### Dibujar ejes: #########
                var max = d3.max(data, function (data) {
                    return data.Total;
                });
                
                var xScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(data.map(function (d) {
                    return d.Edad
                })).range([0, ancho]);
                var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, max]).range([alto, 0]);

                var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
                var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

                CuadroSvg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)").call(y_axis);
                var xAxisTranslate = alto - 20; //donde pondemos el eje X (edades) 
                CuadroSvg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate + ")").call(x_axis);

                //######## Colocacion de barras: ########
                console.log(Espanolas);
                CuadroSvg.selectAll("rect").data(Espanolas).enter().append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(es,i) {
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(es) {
                    return alto - yScale(es);
                })
                .attr("width", (ancho / data.length - dist)) 
                .attr("height", function(d) {return yScale(d);}).attr("transform", "translate(50, -20)");
            });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Datos CSV**

```
Edad,Espanola,Extranjera,Total
15,188,36,224
16,193,53,246
17,214,48,262
18,179,66,245
19,183,49,232
20,181,69,250
21,183,60,243
22,188,68,256
23,188,57,245
24,187,77,264
25,191,79,270
26,195,90,285
27,223,102,325
28,216,126,342
29,219,148,367
30,267,134,401
31,239,174,413
32,263,164,427
33,296,160,456
34,284,160,444
35,329,173,502
36,313,171,484
```

Comment: ***Datos del data.cvs  ***                                           Edad,Espanola,Extranjera,Total
15,188,36,224
16,193,53,246
17,214,48,262
18,179,66,245
19,183,49,232
20,181,69,250
21,183,60,243
22,188,68,256
23,188,57,245
24,187,77,264
25,191,79,270
26,195,90,285
27,223,102,325
28,216,126,342
29,219,148,367
30,267,134,401
31,239,174,413
32,263,164,427
33,296,160,456
34,284,160,444
35,329,173,502
36,313,171,484

Comment: No entiendo bien cual es el problema porque no veo las barras una encima de otra y tampoco veo que no se este generando el eje X en tu imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu pregunta el error esta al momento de usar la escala horizontal `xScale`.

```
CuadroSvg.selectAll("rect").data(Espanolas).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(es,i) {
      return xScale(i);
})
```

En este fragmento de código `i` representa la posición de cada elemento que se encuentra en el array `Espanolas`, es decir del 0 al 22. Entonces como tu dominio en `xScale` son los numeros del 15 al 36 (sacados de la edad), cuando ingresas valores fuera de ese rango (15-36) la función devuelve `undefined` y por tal motivo no obtienes la posición `x`.

La solucion es utilizar directamente `data` y en el `eje x` referenciar la propiedad `Edad` y en el `eje y` referencia `Espanola`

```
CuadroSvg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
.attr("x", function(el) {
    return xScale(el.Edad);
})
.attr("y", function(el) {
    return alto - yScale(el.Espanola);
})
.attr("width", (ancho / data.length - dist)) 
.attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.Espanola)
    })
.attr("transform", "translate(50, -20)");
```

Comment: Eso era sii...  Muchas gracias!!